# In which cases will Oracle create indexes automatically?

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

As far as I know ([this page](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-nonstandard.html#indexes)) Oracle automatically creates an index for each UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY declaration. Is this a complete list of cases when indexes are created automatically in Oracle?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'll try to consolidate given answers and make it community wiki.
So indexes are automatically created by Oracle for such cases:

1. [APC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154091/in-which-cases-will-oracle-create-indexes-automatically/2154368#2154368): For primary key and unique key unless such indexes already exist.
2. [APC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154091/in-which-cases-will-oracle-create-indexes-automatically/2154368#2154368): For LOB storage and XMLType.
3. [Gary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154091/in-which-cases-will-oracle-create-indexes-automatically/2158368#2158368): For table with a nested table.
4. [Jim Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154091/in-which-cases-will-oracle-create-indexes-automatically/2155980#2155980): For materialized view.

Comment: The "LOB storage" case probably also results in indexes for other complex datatypes. Although I haven't tested this. I'd expect indexes to be created by Oracle Spatial, Oracle Text, etc.

Comment: It's community wiki. If you want to add anything, you can just edit this answer.

Answer (score 19):

Firstly, Oracle does not always create an index when we create a primary or unique key.  If there is already an index on that column it will use it instead...

```
SQL> create table t23 (id number not null)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> create index my_manual_idx on t23 ( id )
  2  /

Index created.

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes
  2  where table_name = 'T23'
  3  /

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
MY_MANUAL_IDX

SQL>
```

... note that `MY_MANUAL_IDX` is not a unique index; it doesn't matter ...

```
SQL> alter table t23
  2      add constraint t23_pk primary key (id) using index
  3  /

Table altered.

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes
  2  where table_name = 'T23'
  3  /

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
MY_MANUAL_IDX

SQL> drop index my_manual_idx
  2  /
drop index my_manual_idx
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02429: cannot drop index used for enforcement of unique/primary key


SQL>
```

There is another case when Oracle will automatically create an index: LOB storage....

```
SQL> alter table t23
  2      add txt clob
  3      lob (txt) store as basicfile t23_txt (tablespace users)
  4  /

Table altered.

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes
  2  where table_name = 'T23'
  3  /

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
MY_MANUAL_IDX
SYS_IL0000556081C00002$$

SQL>
```

**edit**

The database treats XMLType same as other LOBs...

```
SQL> alter table t23
  2      add xmldoc xmltype
  3  /

Table altered.

SQL> select index_name from user_indexes
  2  where table_name = 'T23'
  3  /

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
MY_MANUAL_IDX
SYS_IL0000556081C00002$$
SYS_IL0000556081C00004$$

SQL>
```

Comment: I haven't done Oracle for a few years, but I seem to recall that Oracle could use a composite index, if the field being set to UNIQUE (or PRIMARY KEY?) was the first field.  I might be mis-remembering, or it might've changed since the 8i line, so I'd suggest testing it if this would be useful.  (to save from having an extra index and taking the hit in writes)

Comment: An example is always great for understanding.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea if you have a table with an index on it already, but no Primary Key. That is the assumption in your opening sentence. I've never seen different than Primary Keys being created at the moment of table creation, and I don't see why it should be done differently, even if technically you can. The Unique Key is something else ... but really, that should also be setup at moment of table creation. Hence, some index will exist on it.

Comment: @tvCa - clearly you have no experience of loading large amounts of data in a working environment such as a data warehouse.  Some times it can be useful to drop a unique constraint but keep the underlying index.  That requires we build the unique constraint on a pre-created non-unique index. It's not a common scenario but also not an unreasonable one.

Answer (score 4):

No, we're getting closer but that's not quite a complete list yet.

There will also be an index automatically created when you create materialized view since Oracle needs to be able to quickly identify the rows when doing a fast refresh. For rowid based materialized views, it uses I_SNAP$_tablename. For primary key materialized views, it uses the original PK name, modified as necessary to make it unique.

```
create materialized view testmv 
refresh force with rowid
as select * from dual;

select index_name from user_indexes where table_name = 'TESTMV';

Index Name
--------------
I_SNAP$_TESTMV
```

Answer (score 3):

And another one, if you create a table with a nested table you get an index created automatically. Object based storage in general can do this as there can be hidden tables created.

I think schema-based XMLTypes will also do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the complete list. Oracle automatically creates an index for each UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY declaration.

Comment: According to the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2192193/521799) that's not the complete list...