# SEGMENT_NAME = SYS_C004035569 what is it?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, segments

To check Index size I have executed this query :

```
   SELECT owner, segment_name,SEGMENT_SUBTYPE, bytes/1024/1024 mb
 FROM dba_segments
 WHERE owner = 'PROD2015'
 AND segment_type = 'INDEX' ORDER BY bytes desc;
```

So in results i have many indexes (segement_Name) that i don't know what they are :

SYS_C004035569,

SYS_C004035554

SYS_C004035579

BIN$CwhVTaY1SUCvWreTMryvQQ==$0

Can you please explain that to me ?

thanks & regards,

Comment: From where have you found the query?

Comment: there are deleted , and oracle keep them in recyle bin(I guess)

Comment: Looks like this indexes were automatically created by oracle  (for constraints for example ), see here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154091/in-which-cases-will-oracle-create-indexes-automatically

Comment: @Moudiz yes you are right, BIN$CwhVTaY1SUCvWreTMryvQQ==$0 are deleted ones

Comment: @agent5566 thank you for your answer, it helped me to find out what are those indexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SEGMENT_NAME = SYS_C004035569 what is it?

Those are system named objects when you do not explicitly create them but Oracle does it for you. It could be constraints, indexes etc.

For example, if you create a **NOT NULL** constraint, you would see constraint name as `SYS_C`.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(
  2  ID NUMBER NOT NULL
  3  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT constraint_name,
  2    constraint_type,
  3    table_name,
  4    search_condition
  5  FROM user_constraints
  6  WHERE table_name ='T';

CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_TYPE TABLE_NAME SEARCH_CONDITION
--------------- --------------- ---------- ----------------
SYS_C0010726    C               T          "ID" IS NOT NULL

SQL>
```

It is a **CHECK constraint** for the **NOT NULL** condition. If you see the **CONSTRAINT_TYPE** then you would see it as `C`. And the name as **SYS_C** you see is because it is **system-generated name**.

> BIN$CwhVTaY1SUCvWreTMryvQQ==$0

These are objects which are in the **recyclebin**. If you purge the recyclebin, you won't see them.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT OBJECT_NAME, ORIGINAL_NAME FROM recyclebin;

no rows selected

SQL> drop table t;

Table dropped.

SQL> SELECT OBJECT_NAME, ORIGINAL_NAME FROM recyclebin;

OBJECT_NAME                    ORIGINAL_NAME
------------------------------ ---------------
BIN$R7nbYt1KSgWqCT+OEXhaAQ==$0 T

SQL> purge recyclebin;

Recyclebin purged.

SQL> SELECT OBJECT_NAME, ORIGINAL_NAME FROM recyclebin;

no rows selected
```

Comment: Mostly correct. Constraints don't have segments - but indexes do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers especially @agent5566 and @Lalit Kumar B.

You are right those ones were automatically created by oracle, I wrote the next query to identify with which tables are related, I used dba_segments and dba_constraints :

```
SELECT seg.owner as Schema,
seg.segment_name as Index_Name ,
cons.table_name, 
cons.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
seg.bytes/1024/1024 as size_in_MB 
FROM dba_segments seg left join dba_constraints cons on seg.segment_name =  cons.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE seg.owner = 'PROD2015'
AND 
segment_type = 'INDEX' 
ORDER BY bytes desc;
```